# Real value of a complex expression

Tags: syntax

Why is the following lines not correct?

```
Clear[a, b]
a \[Element] Reals;
b \[Element] Reals;
f[z_] := z^2 + 3 z - 2
g = f[a + b I] // Expand
Re[g]
```

The output includes `Im` and `Re`. I've read other questions but the recommendations did not work, like

```
$Assumptions = a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals
```

TIA.

Comment: 1. Use `ComplexExpand` (there is certainly a duplicate for this somewhere) 2. `a \[Element] Reals` does not declare `a` to be real the same way that `a == 1` does not assign `1` to `a`. 3. `$Assumptions` only affects functions that have an `Assumptions` option (so no `Expand` or `Re`)

Comment: Another possibility is `Assuming[a∈Reals && b∈Reals, Re[f[a+b I]]//FullSimplify]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) is only used by functions that have the option [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html), e.g., `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Refine`, `Integrate`.

```
Options[#, Assumptions] & /@ {Simplify, FullSimplify, Refine, Integrate}

(* {{Assumptions :> $Assumptions}, {Assumptions :> $Assumptions}, 
    {Assumptions :> $Assumptions}, {Assumptions :> $Assumptions}} *)

Clear[a, b]

$Assumptions = a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals;

f[z_] := z^2 + 3 z - 2

g = f[a + b I];
```

Then to use `$Assumptions`

```
Re[g // Expand] // Simplify

(* -2 + 3 a + a^2 - b^2 *)
```

Or if you do not expand `g` first

```
Re[g] // FullSimplify

(* -2 + a (3 + a) - b^2 *)
```

Comment: That is interesting, but why does the last command 'fail' when $f(z)$ is changed to $f(z)=z^4 + 3 z - 2$? The first seems to work well.

Comment: @mf67 - simplification of expressions is complicated. You will often have to try different approaches. For `f[z_] := z^4 + 3 z - 2`, `Re[g] // ComplexExpand` works well.